# How do I create an orphan branch from the Github API?

Tags: git, github, github-api

I want to create the `gh-pages` branch from the Github API. Is there an easy way to do this?

If not, how would I create an orphan branch from the Github API?

Comment: A branch with no history. The same as if you type `git checkout --orphan gh-pages` on the command line.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do this by:

1. Check whether the branch already exists
2. If not, then create a commit that refers to git's [empty tree SHA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765453/gits-semi-secret-empty-tree)
3. Then create a ref to that commit

You can find some CoffeeScript example code for how to do that from https://github.com/noflo/noflo-github/blob/master/components/CreateOrphanBranch.coffee#L31

Here is one such branch created this way: https://github.com/the-domains/example.net/tree/branch_1403616324001

**Update**: this method only works if the git repository has previous orphan branches. If it is a newly-created repo created via GitHub's API using the `auto_init` option it won't work. I've contacted GitHub about this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a branch via the [Create a Reference](http://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/#create-a-reference) part of the API. I'm not sure, however, if you can create an orphaned branch with that or if the API would prevent that.

In fact, testing it out with curl doesn't work:

```
curl -X POST -u sigmavirus24 https://api.github.com/repos/sigmavirus24/github3.py/github3.py/refs -d '{"ref":"refs/heads/orphaned"}'
curl -X POST -u sigmavirus24 https://api.github.com/repos/sigmavirus24/github3.py/github3.py/refs -d '{"ref":"refs/heads/orphaned", "sha":""}'
```

Both return:

```
{"message": "Reference update failed"}
```

I tried with and without the `Content-Type` header (`-H "Content-Type: application/json"`) but neither work.

From that minor experimentation, it would appear you can not create an orphaned branch via the API.

Comment: I was able to create a reference with a sha that pointed to a root level commit (a new commit I created with no parents). When creating that commit I wasn't able to create an empty tree reference through the github api, but instead had to create a tree with a dummy file in it. I'm currently using those workarounds but am still interested in seeing if there is a way to create an orphan branch referencing a root level commit pointing to an empty tree.

Comment: This answer breaks down creating a new branch in verbose details https://stackoverflow.com/a/9513594/80434