# How to pull from official/master using github api for authenticated user?

Tags: oauth-2.0, github-api, git-pull, pull

I have oauth2 access_token for user with scope repo which means I can basically access all public/private repos of the user.
I have a local copy of a repo on my machine and I want to pull (fetch and merge) using the authenticated user's token in github api.
 How do I manage this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An OAuth access token, (like [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line)) can be used [from command-line](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line#using-a-token-on-the-command-line):

That OAuth token can be used as a password when GitHub asks for your credentials (username/password) for an HTTPS URL.

Therefore, make sure the remote URL is an HTTPS one, with `<theuser>` username in it

```
    cd /path/to/repo
    git remote -v
    # if origin starts with git@github.com (SSH)
    git remote set-url origin https://<theuser>@github.com/<theuser>/<repo>
```

Whenever you clone/pull/push a private repo from `<theuser>`, enter the OAuth access token as a password.

Or check your `git config credential.helper`: you can [**cache those credentials**](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/caching-your-github-password-in-git#platform-linux), using for instance the GCM (Git Credential Manager) like one for [Mac/Linux](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Mac-and-Linux), or [for Windows](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows).

Note that [`git merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) is a local-only operation, so it won't require any credentials.

Comment: As mentioned above, I only have the user's oauth access token, unless I can use it to get the PAT (which I don't think is the case) then it won't help me.

Comment: @GokuAfrica Still, try and use that access token as password for an HTTPS URL, and see if it is accepted as password.

Comment: Yes it really worked! Thank you. Now I feel so stupid. I must remember now that the oauth 2 token can be substituted for the password for the given user

Comment: please edit the answer to mention oauth2 token rather than PAT token. State that it can be used as a replacement for password. See my own answer to the question. Make those changes and I'll gladly accept your answer

Comment: I want all branches to pull from master when pushed directly to master branch. Is there any solution?

Comment: @DmytroMyronenko pull from when push to? I am not sure to fully understand. Can you make this a separate question with more details?

Answer (score 0):

you can not do it locally, but I think it can be done as from [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)

> git pull is shorthand for git fetch followed by git merge FETCH_HEAD

you can achieve this by following the steps in order

1. create [branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506181/github-api-create-branch/9513594)
2. create a new [commmit](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/#create-a-commit)
3. [update](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/#update-a-reference) branch to point to new commit
4. [merge](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/merging/) the new created branch with you want pull in

Comment: The merge will just merge code from the new branch to existing branches, it has nothing to do with pulling latest code from repo to local machine using the access_token

Comment: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/, this will get you the content, but don't think so you can merge it locally using github api

Comment: Yeah, I saw the contents api. The best solution I got was using the api to download the zip of the entire repository whenever a code merge happens to master but I don't think that's really viable for me.