# How to create a branch using probot (octokit)?

Tags: probot, octokit-js

I want to create a branch using Probot. Seeing that it uses octokit/rest.js, I went over the octokit docs but couldn't find a method to do so. So how do I create a branch?

Also note that I mean to create a branch so I can pull request later.

**Edit:** [This](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/git#create-a-reference) seems to be the way to do it, but it's confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes @Siddharth,

The way to do it is as you pointed. I found this good explanation in StackOverflow: [Github API - create branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506181/github-api-create-branch)

Also, using Octokit SDK, you can easily achieve it like this:

```js
octokit.rest.git.createRef({
  owner,
  repo,
  ref,
  sha,
});
```

docs here: https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v18#git-create-ref