# Creating a new branch using Github API

Tags: c#, .net, github, github-api

I am trying to create a new branch, update a file in that branch, and then create a PR all using the Git API.

To create a branch, I understand that we need to use the Reference API for this, as mentioned in the post - [Github API - create branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506181/github-api-create-branch)

So I create it using the following POST call -

```
/repos/:user/:repo/git/refs
```

with 2 body parameters -

```
ref - new branch name (refs/heads/{new branch})
sha - sha1 value of the master branch.
```

I get a success code. However, when I use the branches API to get a list of all branches, I dont see my newly created one!
The API to get branches is -

```
repos/:user/:repo/branches
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: How many branches does this repository have? Perhaps there are too many and your new branch is on the second or last page?

Comment: You are seeing other branches, correct?

Comment: Are you using any tools like postman to make the requests? If not, you could try this and see if you get a different result.

Comment: @DaytonRumbold - Yes, I see the other branches in the response
Im not using postman, I'm running this from a web app in VS. 
So when I make a get call to /repos/{owner}/{repo}/git/refs/head - I see my newly created reference in there.
But when I make a call to the branches API -  /repos/{owner}/{repo}/branches - I dont see it there.
So I guess the question is, is creating a new reference the only thing needed to create a new branch?

Comment: @knittl - I have only 7 branches in my response, so its not a pagination issue.

Comment: @RJP To answer your question, I don't know if the api can do everything to create a branch from a new reference. Creating a new reference is the starting point.
What the `/repos/:user/:repo/git/refs` API Call doesn't do is switch your local repository to the new branch. `git checkout` can do that. Maybe you need to enter an extra git command in order for it to complete?

Comment: The reason for this was in my body parameter for ref, I was sending in "ref/head/NewBranch" instead of "ref/heads/NewBranch".

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this was in my body parameter for ref, I was sending in "ref/head/NewBranch" instead of "ref/heads/NewBranch".

Comment: But the question states that you sent `refs/heads/…`. VTC "not reproducible or caused by a typo"